# Bibtex Journal isn't shown in the entry

Tags: bibtex

i have the following in my bibliography:

```
@Article{lyness,
  Title                    = {Moderate degree symmetric quadrature rules for the triangle},
  Author                   = {Lyness, J. N. and Jespersen, D.}
  Journal                  = {J. Inst. Appl. Math.},
  Year                     = {1975},
  Pages                    = {19 - 32},
  Volume                   = {15},

  Owner                    = {user},
  Timestamp                = {2014.04.19}
}
```

But when I compile the document (pdflatex - bibtex - pdflatex - pdflatex), the journal in question does not appear in the entry. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Did you use the \cite{NAME} or \nocite{NAME} command in your document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a comma missing at the end of the entry's `author` field. Add the comma and BibTeX should have no further problems with this entry.

If you open the `.blg` file (which is produced by BibTeX) you should be able to find an error message involving something such as

```
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'
```